# Syntax missing ; before statement in mongoexport

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to export mongodb collection with:

```
mongoexport -d InventoryPLC -c Spectra -o spectra.json;
```

but it is giving me error:

> Syntax missing ; before statement

I search on mongodb website and other reference websites:

```
mongoexport -d InventoryPLC -c Spectra;
```

I want to export collection.

I checked stackoverflow examples and mongodb documentation:

```
mongoexport -d InventoryPLC -c Spectra -o spectra.json;
```

I want exported collection, but have had no luck.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Where are you typing this…?

Comment: I am typing in terminal after mongo command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to run `mongoexport` from inside the Mongo shell. That command must be executed outside it, from your OS command shell.

Comment: How mongo will know which database and collection they have to connect?

Comment: By the parameters you are already passing in the command you posted. `mongoexport -d InventoryPLC -c Spectra -o spectra.json;`. `-d` is the database, `-c` is the collection and `-o` is the output file;

Comment: When I am trying to connect directly, it is giving this error:Failed: Failed to parse: { find: "Spectra", filter: {}, sort: {}, skip: 0, snapshot: true, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "InventoryPLC" }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.

Comment: Add the parameter `--forceTableScan`, this way: `mongoexport --forceTableScan -d InventoryPLC -c Spectra -o spectra.json`