# MongoDB: How to properly export a collection from MongoDB to my computer?

Tags: mongodb

Given the following database and related collection **scows.tasks**, how do I export 2GB it for storage purposes so to make space?

[image: storage]

I have been trying to do it using various ways but none of them worked:

```
mongoexport --verbose --db scows --collection tasks --out tasks.json --verbose

mongoexport -vvvv --db scows --username='my_username' --password='my_passwd' --collection tasks --out /home/to/Desktop/storageMongo/tasks.json -f 'my_passwd'

mongoexport --host=127.0.0.1 --db scows --collection tasks --out tasts.json
```

And in doing this I always got the same exact error:

> 2020-02-13T12:55:17.183-0500  will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and
>   SIGKILL 2020-02-13T12:55:20.690-0500  error connecting to db server: no
>   reachable servers

**Posts I used to solve the problem** but that unfortunately didn't help me out:

1) [I used this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594702/syntax-missing-before-statement-in-mongoexport) but nothing happened

2) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041337/mongodb-mongorestore-command-not-found/36544032) also but same results as above

3) [This source](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/export-very-large-data-from-a-mongodb-collection-using-script/) was useful but didn't help me find out the problem

4) [And lastly this one](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mongoexport/) to help me with the command but I always had the same error.

5) Also as mentioned in the official documentation I am using my `Ubuntu 18.04` shell as terminal to input the command instead of the `mongo` shell.

How do I properly export a collection from MongoDB to my computer?

Comment: Did you check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/ - your syntax is wrong, verify it carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try one of suggested option (Ubuntu terminal):

```
#localhost:27017 security disabled
mongoexport --db scows --collection tasks --out /tmp/tasks.json

#some_ip:some_port security disabled
mongoexport --host="some_ip:some_port" --db scows --collection tasks --out /tmp/tasks.json

#some_ip:some_port security enabled
mongoexport --host="some_ip:some_port" --username=user --password=pass --db scows --collection tasks --out /tmp/tasks.json
```

This will export JSON file (no compression) into **/tmp** directory

But if you export with `mongodump` command, you can compress your exported data

```
mongodump --host="some_ip:some_port" --username=user --password=pass --db scows --collection tasks --gzip --out /tmp
```

This will export BSON structured files (compressed) into **/tmp/scows** directory

**EDIT:** Export from MongoDB Atlas, use this:

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb+srv://username:password@vessel-tracker-cluster-x2lpw.mongodb.net/scows" --collection tasks --out /tmp/tasks.json
```

---

```
2020-02-13T20:20:51.387+0100    connected to: mongodb+srv://[**REDACTED**]@vessel-tracker-cluster-x2lpw.mongodb.net/scows
2020-02-13T20:20:52.522+0100    [........................]  scows.tasks  0/XXX  (0.0%)
2020-02-13T20:20:52.642+0100    [########################]  scows.tasks  XXX/XXX  (100.0%)
2020-02-13T20:20:52.643+0100    exported XXX records
```

**EDIT 2:** User has DNS issue which ignores --uri parameter and connects to localhost. Adding public DNS to **resolve.conf**, mongoexport was able to export the data

Comment: Thanks for reading the question, I still have the same connection error. I wonder if `--host="some_ip:some:port"` needs to receive this string: `mongodb+srv://username:password@vessel-tracker-cluster-x2lpw.mongodb.net/trackingtest?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: Ok something is happening: it is connecting to `localhost` but I get this error: `2020-02-13T14:37:37.513-0500 connected to: localhost`
`2020-02-13T14:37:37.530-0500 Failed: Failed to parse: { find: "tasks", filter: {}, sort: {}, skip: 0, snapshot: true, $db: "scows" }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.`

Comment: But I don't know where 'snapshot' is coming from. It is not a field I introduced in the db. I am sure of that.

Comment: Let's continue on [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207793/discussion-between-valijon-and-emanuele)

Comment: @emanuele updated my answer with conclusions. Open new issue to ask community how to solve DNS problem for your Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct because it worked at the end. And meanwhile I am going to post a ticket on the DNS! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: hi Valijon, how are you? I just wanted to let you know that I opened ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339320/mongodb-dns-issue-of-resolv-conf-connecting-to-mongodb) about the DNS issue of last week. Sorry it took me a little long but I wanted to make sure I described the question well, with enough details and with the proper print screen. It was a lot of work. If you could please take a look and tell me if it is clear I would really appreciate that. If not I will edit it. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi. How are you doing? I've updated a bit your question, I hope someone can help you setup correctly DNS. Good luck

Comment: Hi :) I am doing good and what about you? Thanks for the edits. In the meantime I will just export data the way we solved it last week until someone can provide a DNS fix solution. Have a good weekend!